# flex: is there a way to dispach a custom event from one loaded flex application to the other?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, communication

I have an HTML page that loads two different SWF files.
is there a way to dispatch a custom event from one flex application to another ?

to create a custom event I extend the Event class and I add another variable to the constructor called params which is an Object. I use EventDispatcher to dispatch the events.

I have no idea how to do that between one flex application to the other.
is it even possible ?

If it's not, is there any other way that these two flex applications can communicate without opening a LocalConnection ?

Using flex 4.5

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On same page, you can use ExternalInterface to pass data through Javascript helper function. But LocalConnection is easier because it is direct.

Comment: unfortunately LocalConnection does not work 100% of the time. it works 98% of the time but that's not good enough.